# Ajax in Codeigniter with jQuery, how to send back data?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

How do I send data from the controller back to the view?

say I have the following search controller:

```
function search()
{
$search_text = $this->input->post('company');

$data['found_companies'] = $this->Company->get_companies_by_name($search_text);
$data['page_title'] = 'Search';
$this->load->view('head', $data);
$this->load->view('pages/after_search', $data);
$this->load->view('footer');
}
```

I get back the search results from the model from the model into `$data['found_companies']`, how do I pass it as the Ajax return data?

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
 function search()
    {
    $search_text = $this->input->post('company');

    $data['found_companies'] = $this->Company->get_companies_by_name($search_text);
        /*
        $data['page_title'] = 'Search';
        $this->load->view('head', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/after_search', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
       */ //Remove these part as it will display your view
    return json_encode($data['found_companies']);

    }
```

with the Ajax request (i.e with jQuery);

```
$.post('search',myData,function(result){
  console.log(result); //found_companies
});
```

Comment: Thanx, but I get some wired result: the console gives me back the whole page source! and the search results appear inside the div of the search form... do you know why is that and how do i get only the results?

Comment: I use CakePHP, and there is a way to don't display the page using `$this->autoRender = false`. Maybe CodeIgniter has the same kind of stuff :).. To display the result into a div, use `$('#myDiv').html(result);`

Comment: I use `console.log(result);` and the `result` is the whole page code (as if copy-pasting page soursce), do you know how do i get *only* the results?

Comment: Just remove all your `$this->load->...` stuff. This will stop displaying your page aka your code in the console... :)

Answer (score 0):

With a CI ajax call, all you need to do is echo a JSON object containing the information, not load the views. The views should be loaded on page load by the page controller. The ajax contollers should be separate.

Vid about it here http://geekhut.org/2009/06/how-to-codeigniter-jquery-json/